# Analytic cycles on complex-analytic spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, algebraic-cycles

If $X$ is a proper smooth complex analytic space, one can define Chow groups of **analytic** cycles on $X$ the usual way.

We have a cycle map

$$c^p_X: \text{CH}^p(X) \to \text{H}^{2p}_{D}(X,\mathbf{Z}(p))$$
to Deligne cohomology of $X$.

Is $c^p_X$ an isomorphism? Is $c^p_X\otimes\mathbf{Q}$ an isomorphism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your definition, wouldn't $CH^p(X)$ coincide with the usual Chow group when $X$ is smooth projective, by GAGA? And of course Deligne cohomology would be the same. So the answers should be no and no,
for a general  variety $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an example of a smooth projective variety for which $c^p_X$ is not surjective? I have some examples for non injective $c^p_X$. In other words, surjectivity of $c^p_X\otimes\mathbf{Q}$ is conjectured only onto $\text{Hdg}^{p,p}(X)\otimes\mathbf{Q}$, but not onto the full $H^{2p}_D(X,\mathbf{Z}(p))$. Correct?

Comment: $c^p_X$ and  $c^p_X\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ are usually not surjective (for $p>1$). Indeed, if $c^p_X$ were surjective, its restriction to the group $CH^p(X)_{hom}$ of cohomologically trivial cycles would surject onto the intermediate Jacobian $J^p(X)$. 
 But for a general hypersurface of sufficiently high degree  in $\mathbb{P}^{2p}$, Griffiths proved long time ago that the image  of $c^p_X$ is countable.